DSP VS FPGA for Power electronics Solar inverters
I need some help regarding the use of an FPGA or DSP for the control loop of the three-phase solar inverter. I want to implement a digital feedback system (as shown below) instead of analog and therefore am looking for the best result. in real time. I am starting from scratch an have some knowledge about both of them. I want to ask which one is better in its working in these applications and what do mostly people use??

I also want to have some Iot based monitoring system in my inverter. Also, I have seen some people using a combination of DSPs and FPGAs. How does that combination work and what is the advantage of it??

doesn't a part of the FPGA act as a DSP when it is in circuit?

There are plenty of MCUs and DSPs with built-in peripherals that are specifically intended for applications related to 3-phase power -- both generation and consumption. There is rarely a need to bring the extra complexity of an FPGA and its toolchain into the picture unless you're doing something really unusual.

@DaveTweed can you name some DSPs for the purpose.

I’d suggest having a peruse of websites such as Ti.com and analog.com. Motor drives and inverters are big business so just about all the major semi companies have offerings.  You’d have to be doing something exotic to go down the fpga path these days.  Even standard microcontrollers can cope with simpler inverters like you are proposing. - STM32, Kinetis, TMS570. What do you call ‘Real Time’? It helps to scope this as real time could be nanoseconds to some or milliseconds to others.

I’d suggest you get your hands on a dead solar inverter for the purposes of seeing how others have solved the problem. My local junk yard frequently has single phase ones for $10or $20. Bonus points if you fix it.

We don't do product recommendations here, but I've worked with some Microchip products in this area.

@Kartman Also  I have seen some boards with a combination of FPGA and DSP processors in them. Is there a specific reason for its use together or a simple DSP can do my task?

What vintage are these examples? FPGAs can provide you with specific pwm generation, but modern microcontrollers that are targetted to inverter and motor drives have fancy pwm generation and monitoring esp for 3 phase. For a 3phase mains inverter, I wouldn’t expect the computing to be too onerous so a modern dsp might be overkill. So, it is debatable whether you’d need a FPGA or DSP for your application. How to choose is always a challenge. - you need to create some specifications and select devices based on that.  Looking at existing products can give a clue.
